# Using WhatsApp API to find out if a number has an account

Tags: api, whatsapp

I'm trying to use the WhatsApp API, especially "POST /v1/contacts" at this url "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/contacts/".

But actually I don't know which url to use, I tried "https://api.whatsapp.com/v1/contacts" but I got a 404 Not Found Status.

I do my queries on postman.

Has anyone ever used it.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not from public server you should host webapp.

Comment: https://checkwa.online/wp/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you'd need to try a different method because the API you're trying to call is not a public API, it's a private API.

Access private API is only available to verified Whatsapp for Business accounts.
It's [Whatsapp For Business service provider](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/whatsapp-business-api/working-with-solution-providers/?lang=en) you choose and successfully applied for.